# Calculation about ( Showing n to n of total n ) in pagination

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pagination, primeng

### Calculation about ( Showing n to n of total n ) in primeng data table pagination

---

I have create a custom logic to want to showing current  records from remaining records logic

If table row count is 10 and total count and if am on the second page, then I could display like ,

`Showing 20 to 30 of 37`

So am try to do this in `(onPage)="onPageChange($event)"` event with manually

```
onPageChange(e) {
        console.log(e);
        let currentpageCount = parseInt(e.first.toString().charAt(0)) + 1;
        let currentPageRows = e.rows;
        this.pageinationcount = 'Showing' + (parseInt(e.first.toString().charAt(0)) * parseInt(currentPageRows)) + ' to ' + (currentpageCount * parseInt(currentPageRows)) + ' of ' + this.errorLogList.length
    }
```

> Everything is working fine, but if my last page having only 7 records but the `e.rows` result is always showing `10`. I know `e.rows` works from this input which am giving in data table as `[rows]="10"`. But in this scenario how can we solve this??

Comment: `howvto correctly tag a question` Can you tell me where I did incorrect?

Comment: Click on all of them, read the info text. Third one is not applicable

Comment: go to this URL and kindly understand what is primefaces and what is priming https://www.primefaces.org/primeng

Comment: Also priming is not an popular, So if we  want answer then we can able to tag relevant technologies.

Comment: Hmmmm..., sorry, I think **you** should do that. 'Relevant' being the important part here... Angular is a relevant technology for PrimeNG, PrimeFaces is JSF based, and **not** angular based. The fact that PrimeFaces was their first framework and they use that same url for PrimeNG does not make the PrimeFaces **technology** relevant to PrimeNG or Angular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
let start = e.first + 1;
let end = (e.first + e.rows) > this.errorLogList.length ? this.errorLogList.length : (e.first + e.rows);
this.pageinationcount = 'Showing ' + start + ' to ' + end + ' of ' + this.errorLogList.length;
```

Changed Aravind's example a little bit for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/oWrGziGmkwXfO4aK9xOp?p=preview

Comment: My pleasure:) .

Answer (score 0):

I have manually done something with passing the `dt.dataToRender.length` in (onpage) event

```
 <p-dataTable class="ui-widget-h1-header1" [value]="errorLogList" 
 [responsive]="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10"
 (onPage)="onPageChange($event, dt.dataToRender.length)" [globalFilter]="gb" 
 #dt [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,25,30]">
 .
 .
 .
 .
</p-dataTable>
```

Below code is working only if the row count is `10`, but if the row counts are `20|25|30` it's not working as expected

```
 onPageChange(e, pagecount) {
        console.log(e);
        let currentpageCount = parseInt(e.first.toString().charAt(0)) + 1;
        let calculateRow = parseInt(e.rows) - parseInt(pagecount)
        this.pageinationcount = parseInt(e.first.toString()) + 1
            + ' to ' + (parseInt(e.first.toString()) - calculateRow) + ' of ' + (this.errorLogList.length)

        let temp = 'Showing' + this.pageinationcount.toString();
        this.pageinationcount = temp;
    }
```

---

> But am struggling to handle if the row counts are `20|25|30|etc` . Kindly take my answer as a key for your answers.